# Grunt cli not setting system path

Tags: node.js, npm, gruntjs, grunt-cli

I have install grunt on my server via the setup instructions on the grunt website.

Using the `npm install -g grunt-cli`

However I still can get my console to recognize the grunt command. I can see any linking in my system variables path directory so im guessing this is probably the issue. Does anyone know what should be in the path directory to make the console pick up the grunt command.

Any help would be great, I only have the issue on my windows server on my machine is fine.

Error is

The term 'grunt' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program;

Cheers

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found it in the end with grunt-cli if it fails to set the enviroment variable you need to set it in your system variables under path.

Mine for example was

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator.####\Application Data\npm

Answer (score 0):

Current grunt version does that automatically unless until you don't have write permission's on your file system.

Comment: This was the case for myself working as administrator in the PowerShell. Bizarre!